# Filling combobox by selecting value from other combobox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagrid

I am get the below error,
My code is:

```
Private Sub Cmb_name_final_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  
     Handles Cmb_name_final.SelectedIndexChanged

    Cbofill(dsetreg, "select* from Student_info where ID=" & 
          Me.Cmb_name_final.SelectedValue & "", Me.Cmb_reg_final, 
         "Student_registration", "ID")

End Sub
```

Giving the error:

```
Operator '&' is not defined for string "select* from Student_info where " and type 'DataRowView'.
```

Comment: Please show the code where you fill your combobox with data.

Comment: My code is above ... in the select index changed event of combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show the code for the `CboFill()` method to give a more complete question.

However, your problem is simply that you are trying to concatenate a string (`"select *..."`) with a DataRowView (`Me.Cmb_name_final.SelectedValue`).

Update your code to access the column of the DataRowView that contains the value you want to query with and you should move beyond this error. Something like `DirectCast(Me.Cmb_name_final.SelectedValue, DataRowView)("ID")`.

The whole thing might look something like this:

```
Private Sub Cmb_name_final_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cmb_name_final.SelectedIndexChanged 
    Cbofill(dsetreg, "select* from Student_info where ID="& DirectCast(Me.Cmb_name_final.SelectedValue, DataRowView)("ID") &"", Me.Cmb_reg_final, "Student_registration", "ID") 
End Sub
```

Comment: it works but when i select second record then it gives that error....
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.